# How is visual programming using nodes and links converted into code?

Tags: c++

as title says, i want to know what is logic behind visual programming and how is it being converted into code?

Use for example unreal engine 4 blueprints, how it all works behind scenes?

I somehow think everything is made using linked structures with pointers... For example:" if " statement needs link of statement and to output links, wether that statement is true or false... But if we do all like that, programming every keyword seperatly, i think it would take too much time.
I hope you understand what im thinking.

I would from the point of view of  c++ explaination if possible..

Answer (score 5):

Usually data flow graphs are not converted into C, C++ or similar before being compiled. A visual representation of a data flow graph is much closer to an *Abstract Syntax Tree* (AST) than written programming language code.

In fact, for most programming language compilers among the first steps carried out is the translation of a the written code into an AST, and it's a trivial task to feed such a AST into a program like graphviz to generate a call graph or similar from it.

So in a sense, that data flow graph of Unreal, or LabVIEW or similar programming environments is already one step closer to the executable code. Hence regarding your questions it's better suited to reformulate it as *"how is written programming language parsed and translated into a data flow graph – like you can draw in Unreal engine – or an AST?"*.

Unfortunately the answer to this would go vastly beyond the scope of StackOverflow, and I'll simply refer you to the standard literature on compiler development.

Comment: Okay, thank you for answer. I hope i will get some more informations about this.   Any links where i can start learning it?

Comment: @NikolaBozin: It's really an extremely vast field, in fact compiler development and everything that comes with it is a specialized major topic of computer science. There are a number of books on it. The most well known one is the ["dragon book" (so named because of the motive on it's cover)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Personally I'm more fond of ["Modern Compiler Design" by Dirk Grund et. al](https://www.dickgrune.com/Books/MCD_2nd_Edition/). Also https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aplatzer/course/Compilers/waitegoos.pdf looks nice.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.